# Get all types with some type included in properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I read type from loaded assemblies:

```
var someType = loadedAssemblies
 .Where(a => a != null && a.FullName.StartsWith("MY."))
 .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
 .Distinct()
 .ToArray()[0];
```

Type name is "AddressesRevisionContainerId".

Now i have this 2 classes:

```
public class RevisionContainer {
  public RevisionContainer(RevisionContainerId revisionContainerId)
  {
    this.RevisionContainerId = revisionContainerId;
  }

  public virtual RevisionContainerId RevisionContainerId { get; private set;}
}

public class AddressesRevisionContainerId : RevisionContainerId
{}
```

If you have someType, how can you find all classes, which have this type included?
For example, how can I find from type "SomeType" that it is included in RevisionContainer class (and maybe some other class)?

Comment: What do you mean by "included"? Do you mean you´re looking for classes that have a reference to that type? I can´t seen `SomeType` in your example by the way.

Comment: It's the other way around, the `AddressesRevisionContainerId`-class "includes" the `RevisionContainerId` because that is it's parent-class. The `RevisionContainer` doesn't need to know (or "include") the chilld-class(es).

Comment: I get someType from loadedAssemblies, as you can see and it's name is "AddressesRevisionContainerId". If you see this class you can see that it is inherited from "RevisionContainerId" class. And "RevisionContainerId" class is property of class RevisionContainer. And RevisionContainer class is what I'm looking for (and all others if exists).

Comment: `Included`? or did you mean inherited?

Comment: So you need to check it's properties and check it's type if it is derived from `RevisionContainerId`

Comment: I have one serialized object and all I know is that it includes somewhere in its three "AddressesRevisionContainerId". RevisionContainer as described,  is one example, but could be also direct property or similar. So, at deserialization I would like to loop over all possible objects until one is successfully deserialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the types in your assemblies and check for every type if any of it's properties type is equal to some type or if some type is sub class of it:

```
var typesThatHasSomeTypeAsProperty = 
    assemblies.SelectMany(assembly => 
      assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => 
        type.GetProperties().Any(property => 
          property.PropertyType == someType || someType.IsSubclassOf(property.PropertyType)))).ToList();
```

Comment: Why would you `Distinct` it? Expect duplicate types?

Comment: I get error at "type =>type.GetProperties" - it says:"type.GetProperties(BindingFlags)" is a method which is not valid in the given context. There is missing (): type.GetProperties()

Comment: True, `GetProperties` is a method. I assume that this is some sort of Pseudo code. So some minor typo's could occur. You might know how to solve them. You might use: `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public)`

Comment: Thanks. I have found 23 types this way and only one is the right one.In loop i can deserialize until one is successfull. I guess this is the only way?

Comment: @Simon this method will give all the types that answers your condition, what you should do next is dependent on what you need to do with these types.

Comment: Thanks. I have class with deserialize method, which needs the right type to deserialize to proper object. So, I try with all types until one is ok:
foreach (Type curType in typesThatHasSomeTypeAsProperty)
   var myObject=SomeClass.Deserialize<curType>(_streamedData)
It works, I just would like to know if there is some more efficient way to find the right type of some serialized object.